# Arrangement of particles in g-field zero angular momentum.

Tags: gravity, angular-momentum

Is it possible to have an arrangement of masses gravitationally interacting with each over put into motion such that the system has zero net angular momentum but no collisions or particles escaping to infinity? (my suspicion is no).

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible. Take a two-planet system where the planets orbit in opposite directions. Have the planets' masses be equal, but small enough so that their interaction is swamped by their interaction with the central sun, thus giving them stable orbits. The outer planet's angular momentum will be greater than the inner planet's, and the sun will have an angular momentum component for each planet that is in the same direction and increases with the planet's mass.

If you now reduce the mass of the outer planet, its angular momentum (and the sun's related angular momentum) will decrease. Continue decreasing the outer planet's mass until the four angular momentums balance. Et voilà!